# Fetch XML with apollo, query response with null

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I want to fetch XML with Apollo.
I am using https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml as example

```
import { RestLink } from "apollo-link-rest";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
const { parseString } = require("xml2js");

const parseXmlResponseToJson = (xml) => {
  return parseString(xml, (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
    //  {note: {to: Array(1), from: Array(1), heading: Array(1), body: Array(1)}}

    return JSON.stringify(result);
  });
};

const restLink = new RestLink({
  uri: "https://www.w3schools.com",
  responseTransformer: async (response) =>
    response.text().then((text) => parseXmlResponseToJson(text)),
});

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: restLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

And my query

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const GET_CDS = gql`
  query MyQuery {
    cds @rest(type: "note", path: "/xml/note.xml") {
      note {
        to
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Now, when I try to use the data in my React component

```
function Component() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS);
  console.log('data', data.cds)
  ...
```

I get this
[image]

Comment: no unique fields (id or _id), nested type (each brackets means type as apollo is normalizing cache) has no type annotation, no ids, too ... start with normal [target-like] json source then adapt rest response to requirements

Comment: Can you give me a query example?

Comment: query doesn't matter ... not all data structures can be stored in cache, start with normal graphql/json data ... check types/what is stored and how ... you must understand this before work with not compatible data sources

Comment: It is always working when I am using JSON. The challenge is, that this feed is xml

Comment: compare (show) json response with transformer result?